# Wavelet transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, wavelet

Suppose I have a wave with $20 \textrm{ kHz}$, $100 \textrm{ kHz}$ and $300 \textrm{ kHz}$. Sampling frequency used is $1000 \textrm{ kHz}$. I apply the discrete wavelet transform on the wave like `dwt(wave,'db2')`. I will get one level of approximation and detail coefficients. According to the basics, the detail coefficient will have  $300\rm k$ component and approximation coefficient will have the $100\rm k$ and $20\rm k$ components

But when I did `fft` on the output(on approximation and detail), I didn't get what I expected.

- Could anyone post some MATLAB code with which I can verify it?
- And also tell whether I am doing the procedure correctly?
- Also if anyone could explain the practical side of this tool?

Comment: Can you include the results of what you've done so far ? (e.g. your unexpected `fft` output, code)

Comment: mmm I dont think so. The detail coefficients should capture the content in the range $250kHz-500kHz$ and the approximation ones those in the range $0-250kHz$ shouldn't them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be forgetting is that `dwt` does downsampling. After filtering (low-pass or high-pass), the filtered signal is subsampled. In order to keep the number of samples. So aliasing may occur, depending on the quality of the filters.

And `db2` is a quite poor filter. So if you `idwt` either approx or details, by replacing the other coefficients by zeros, you almost get your coefficients in order: on the top, the original signal,  the two low frequencies in the second plot, the high frequencies in the third plot. Of course you have some aliasing, due to the poor resolution.

[image: DWT db2]

Try the attached code with `db24`, you will get much less artifact.

[image: DWT db24]

What happens now with the approximation and the details? My interpretation is that the approximation is now sampled at $500$ kHz, and the details too, except that it is now aliased to the base-band:

[image: DWT coefficients]

and they need to be unmixed by reciprocal filters of the `idwt`.

The [`FFTR.m`](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Documents-Common/FFTR.m) code should be downloaded.

But why study sines with discrete  wavelets?

```
f = [20/1000  100/1000  300/1000];
nSample = 1024; time = (1:nSample)';
data = cos(2*pi*time*f);
dataSum = sum(data,2);
waveName = 'db2';
[a,d] = dwt(dataSum,waveName);
z = zeros(size(a));

dataSumD = idwt(z,d,waveName);
dataSumA = idwt(a,z,waveName);

timeAD = 1:2*length(a);
timeAD=timeAD(1:2:end);

figure(1)
subplot(3,2,1)
plot(time,dataSum);axis tight
subplot(3,2,2)
plot(FFTR(dataSum));axis tight

subplot(3,2,3)
plot(time,dataSumA);axis tight
subplot(3,2,4)
plot(FFTR(dataSumA));axis tight

subplot(3,2,5)
plot(time,dataSumD);axis tight
subplot(3,2,6)
plot(FFTR(dataSumD));axis tight

figure(2)
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(timeAD,a);axis tight
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(FFTR(a,2));axis tight

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(timeAD,d);axis tight
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(FFTR(d,2));axis tight
```

So you have the code, I do not know whether you did stuff correctly, and wavelets are quite useful if used widely on signals that are worth  it. Sines typically are not on the  list.